# Installed a module PyInputPlus from Mac terminal, but atom IDE cannot find it

Tags: python, python-import, atom-editor

I installed PyInputPlus from my Mac terminal:

```
pip install --user PyInputPlus
```

However, when I try importing and using this module in my Atom IDE code, I get an ImportError.

My code:

```
import PyInputPlus as pyip

while True:
    prompt = "Want to know how to keep an idiot busy for hours?\n"
    response = pyip.inputYesNo(prompt)
    if response == "no":
        break
print("Cheers, have a nice day.")
```

I get the following response:
`ImportError: No module named PyInputPlus`

What do I have to do to get this module working in Atom?

Comment: It seems that the problem was that my Script package on atom IDE used an older Python version by default. When I switched the the Script package to run Python3, the problem disappeared and atom recognised pyinputplus module.

Comment: However, I am still unsure why pyinputplus is not recognised when I use older Python version (2.7.16), but is recognised when I use a more recent version (3.8.1). Did my pip install only install this module for the most recent Python version?